# Can't get SSH public key authentication

Tags: windows, git, ssh, cygwin, svc

I have a notebook and a remote PC based on Windows 7 which have a static IP (for example 10.10.10.10). I want create a ssh-tunnel for my work. So I installed cygwin and share port 2222 for ssh-connection. Now, when I enter on my local PC in sh.exe

```
ssh -v Test@10.10.10.10 -p 2222
```

I see connection log and after this remote PC ask me for password of user "Test". When I enter password - all ok, I get access to remote PC.

But I'm very lazy and I don't want everytime enter password. So, I want create a ssh-keypair for this connection. For this I enter on remote host

```
ssh-keygen -t dsa -b 1024
```

and get a id_dsa & id_dsa.pub

Then I copy key from *C:\cygwin\home\Test.ssh\id_dsa.pub* to *C:\cygwin\home\Test.ssh\authorized_keys*, move DSA keypair to my local PC and put they to my ~/.ssh

Also I create a rule in my local ~/.ssh/config :

```
Host remotepc
    HostName 10.10.10.10
    Port 2222    
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_dsa
```

Now, when i want create ssh connection to remote PC

```
ssh -v Test@remotepc -p 2222
```

I see this log:

```
OpenSSH_6.6.1, OpenSSL 1.0.1i 6 Aug 2014
debug1: Reading configuration data /c/Users/Andrey/.ssh/config
debug1: /c/Users/Andrey/.ssh/config line 5: Applying options for remotepc
debug1: Hostname has changed; re-reading configuration
debug1: Reading configuration data /c/Users/Andrey/.ssh/config
debug1: Connecting to 10.10.10.10 [10.10.10.10] port 2222.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /c/Users/Andrey/.ssh/id_dsa type 2
debug1: identity file /c/Users/Andrey/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.6.1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_6.7
debug1: match: OpenSSH_6.7 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com none
debug1: sending SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_INIT
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ECDSA 5a:a8:bf:df:d0:4a:ee:8c:55:29:89:80:19:41:a9:4e
debug1: Host '[10.10.10.10]:2222' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /c/Users/Andrey/.ssh/known_hosts:8
debug1: ssh_ecdsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering DSA public key: /c/Users/Andrey/.ssh/id_dsa
Connection closed by 10.10.10.10
```

After this I have no access to remote PC. Maybe sshd_config from remote PC can help you and you can help me.

```
Port 2222

PubkeyAuthentication yes

UsePrivilegeSeparation yes

Subsystem   sftp    /usr/sbin/sftp-server
```

Can anyone help me why I cann't connect with DSA keypair? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I have had some problems with ssh and just resolved one. This problem is slightly different but the yours also involves renamed host which could be a problem.

Execute ssh in level 3 verbose mode with the -vvv option for the most detailed debug information.

If that doesn't provide more information then try renaming the config file to config.backup and then issuing the following command:

```
ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_dsa -v Test@10.10.10.10 -p 2222 'exit'
```

The apparent abrupt termination of the session may not be as it seems so the exit may return the error status of ssh.

Comment: Thanks for advice. In my case it was closed router port. Problem solved.